# Intent resolution - implicit intent with data from ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I am suffering from Intent resolution mechanism.

I have a content provider:

```
<provider
 android:authorities="com.company.app"
 android:name=".content.MyProvider"
 android:exported="false" />
```

I have an Activity:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.DetailedFlowActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.LauncherActivity">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.company.app.EDIT_CATEGORY" />

            <action android:name="com.company.app.ANOTHER_EDIT_ACTION" />

            <data
                android:scheme="content"
                android:host="com.company.app"

                />


        </intent-filter>
   <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activity.LauncherActivity" />
</activity>
```

The provider has two specific paths (that is, two tables in the SQLite db), and the `Activity` itself knows how to query both the paths. So I declare `<data>` with the authority and scheme only, assuming that would be enough to resolve the intent.

**The problem is:**  whenever I do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DetailedFlowActivity.ACTION_EDIT_CATEGORY);
intent.setData(
       Uri.withAppendedPath(CategoryItemContract.CONTENT_URI,   
       String.valueOf(categoryId)));

startActivity(intent);
```

I would expect the Intent to resolve to `DetailedFlowActivity`, but it fails telling me that no appropriate `Activity` is found to handle such intent: where action=com.company.app.EDIT_CATEGORY and data=content://com.company.app/categories/123

I could of course turn to using explicit intent, as the stuff happens inside MY application, but I would rather make it in beautiful RESTful approach :)

Help appreciated.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving- there is a note there that you should read.

Comment: @Luksprog, thank you for forcing me re-read this doc :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now I got it. Luksprog's comment forced me to read again the [Intent resolution documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Resolution), and pay a bit more attention to URI data matching part.

**First**, specify CATEGORY_DEFAULT, as the intent is implicit. That is necessary, and I missed the thing.

**Second**, though it says:

> An intent that contains a URI but no MIME type (neither explicit nor
>   inferable from the URI) passes the test only if its URI matches the
>   filter's URI format and the filter likewise does not specify a MIME
>   type

I found that in case of my `ContentProvider` I **need** to specify MIME type to intent-filter. And split my intent-filter into two filters by action:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.company.app.EDIT_CATEGORY" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:scheme="content"
                android:host="com.trustydroid.xpense"
                android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vdn.categories"
                />

 </intent-filter>
```

.. and similarly the other one.

Hope this helps.